# __call catches static method calls

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, getter-setter

I'm using both the magic methods [_*call*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) and [_callStatic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) for my own implementation of something like an ORM/Activerow. They're mainly meant for catching certain function calls:  `__call` is responsible for getters and setters, and `__callStatic` for `findBy` methods (e.g. `findById`).

To map foreign keys, i'm trying to convert calls to e.g. `getArticle` to return the value of `Article::findById()`. To do that, i'm using this case inside my `__call`:

```
if (strstr($property, "_id")) {  
 return $foreignClass::findById($this->getId()); 
}
```

where `$property` is the substring after *set* or *get* in `__call`, and `$foreignClass` the rest of the string. So, in the case of the call `getArticle`, $property would be get and `$foreignClass` would be `Article`.

I've placed some echoes to ensure that the values are correct. However, my `__call` method gets called instead of my `__callStatic`. If i make an implicit static method `findById`, it does get called (so it does recognize it as a static call). If i specifically call `Article::findById()`, `__call` also catches it.

Is this an error with the relatively new `__callStatic`, or am i doing something wrong?

EDIT:
The problem seems to reside in this part:

> _call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.
>   __callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

Though i am calling it on a class, i am calling it from an object context. Is there a way to get into the static context in this case?

Comment: I have dreadful feeling that there's important information missing here. In which class(es) are the magic methods defined? On which class(es) are they called? Are the classes mentioned earlier members of the same inheritance tree? If so, what is their relationship?

Comment: The inheritance tree here is DBObject(Of which i showed the code here)->Article->Activity. Article and Activity override no relevant code, all of this logic happens in DBObject. I've now changed my code to use __get and __set instead of __call, and it seems to be triggering __callStatic properly now.

Comment: So `$foreignClass` is `Article` and the method is being invoked in the context of an `Activity`. That makes `Article` an ancestor class. There's the problem.

Comment: $foreignClass is indeed Article in this case. The variable refers to the table/object the foreign key is referring to. In this case, it's the Article that Activity is pointing to, but it might just as well be a Comment pointing to an Article (Comment is a subclass of DBObject as well). The plan was to make the only real difference in implementation here what the class is called; It uses that name to insert into the correct table. Since Article and Activity both don't override the magic methods, shouldn't they both act the same, as DBObjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code you give runs in the context of an `Activity` object and since the value of `$foreignClas` is `Article`, which is an ancestor of `Activity`, PHP assumes that you are intending [to call an ancestor's implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) of the method.

To break out of the object context there is AFAIK no option other than this absolutely hideous technique:

```
$id = $this->getById();
return call_user_func(
    function() use($foreignClass, $id) { 
        return call_user_func("$foreignClass::findById", $id);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. I read about it before but somehow went back to assuming that :: just called static methods. I'll look a bit further into this, but this is at least a nice source of what :: actually does do :)

Answer (score 0):

The `__callStatic` magic method was only introduced in PHP 5.3.  Prior to that, I believe static calls were routed through `__call` just like normal method calls.  My guess would be that you are using a PHP version that is < 5.3.  What is the output of `php -v` on the command line?

Comment: I've just upgraded to 5.4 to be able to use __callStatic... I'll test a bit to see if it works at all.