# Laravel Eloquent - accessing parent model from child model returns child model

Tags: php, laravel

Extending Eloquent models seems to be a [thing](https://tighten.co/blog/extending-models-in-eloquent) people do. I have an interesting issue:

#### FooBase.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FooBase extends Model {
     protected $table = 'foo_bar';
}
```

#### FooExtends.php

```
namespace App\Models;

class FooExtends extends FooBase {
     public function method() {
           return FooBase::first(); // or even parent::first()
     }
}
```

Calling `(new FooExtends())->method()` returns an instance of `FooExtends` instead of `FooBase`. (Just static methods affected, which may answer my own question, but one would think Laravel would handle this. Calling `(new FooBase())->first()` from within the child class works.) What's going on here?

PHP 7.3, Laravel 5.7

Comment: well if you're calling method from FooExtends, of course it will return an instance of fooextends

Comment: I would have also expected to return an instance of FooBase like you

Comment: @GhiffariAssamar Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really interesting PHP quirk that [doesn't apply static context when calling an ancestor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232445/call-catches-static-method-calls).

Basically, the "static" call to `FooBase::first()` gets interpreted the same as `parent::first()`, because PHP knows that `FooBase` is the parent of the current class context `FooExtends`. And since calls to `parent` stay within the context of the current object, the `first()` call ends up being routed to `__call()` and not `__callStatic()` (which would create a new context using the `FooBase` class).

Really interesting thing to learn about PHP internals and class contexts. Thanks for giving me a reason to poke around. :)

Comment: Whoah, wild, but this makes perfect sense. Thanks for taking the time to poke around!